# Firebase Authentication: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-authentication

Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID.

My Code:

if(strOTP.equals("null")) {}
else {
PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationCode, strOTP);
SigninWithPhone(credential);
}

All the settings on Firebase project are correct still I'm getting this error and my app is crashing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: please provide crash log